# EventToCommandBehavior throws InvalidOperationException in MAUI for checkbox

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I need to run a command once a checkbox is checked/unchecked. The checkboxes are rendered in the page via StackLayout's items source, EventToCommandBehavior is from MAUI CommunityToolkit.

The exception is thrown when the page should be rendered, most likely when XAML is parsed and processed. The Exception message says: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.", which is not very helpful (I am missing what state, who is owner, what is invalid).

Maybe a callstact would help someone?

```
  at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Binding.ApplyRelativeSourceBinding(BindableObject targetObject, BindableProperty targetProperty) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Binding.cs:line 152
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
  at Android.App.SyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:line 36
  at Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:line 36
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:line 84
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrap
```

I've used the same technique several times in Xamarin. It works there as expected, but in MAUI following code throws InvalidOperationException. The content page and view model are created (the constructors pass) correctly, but somewhere later something throws an exception, and honestly don't know why.

```
<StackLayout 
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding GameVariants}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="bindable:SelectExpansion">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <CheckBox
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsExpansion}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Selected}">
                    <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="CheckedChanged"
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:SelectExpansionsPageViewModel}}, Path=SelectExpansionCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                </CheckBox>
                <Label Text="{Binding Expansion}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

The code behind contains only setting context via dependency.

```
public partial class SelectExpansionsPage : ContentPage
{
    public SelectExpansionsPage(SelectExpansionsPageViewModel vm)
    {
        BindingContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And here is View model for page.

```
public partial class SelectExpansionsPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public SelectExpansionsPageViewModel(Game state)
    {
        GameVariants = new ObservableCollection<SelectExpansion>(AvailableExpansions.Expansions.Select(item =>
        {
            item.Selected = state.Expansions.Contains(item.Expansion);

            return item;
        }));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SelectExpansion> GameVariants { get; }
    
    [RelayCommand]
    public void SelectExpansion(SelectExpansion item)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Select item changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch the order of statements in constructor. Set BindingContext LAST; you want everything to be ready before Maui attempts to perform bindings.

Comment: Thanks, @ToolmakerSteve, in fact, I've already used it at the beginning, but order doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Test that Binding Source when NOT part of `toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior`. Add to `SelectExpansionsPageViewModel` the member `public string TestString { get; set; } = "TEST"`, and change ItemTemplate label to `<Label Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:SelectExpansionsPageViewModel}}, Path=TestString}"`. If that works, then I think you have found a bug in `EventToCommandBehavior`, when used inside an `ItemTemplate`. Add issue at maui-community-toolkit github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I've found that behaviors aren't part of the visual tree (sorry, lost the link).

To overcome this one has to reference source binding via the reference, see the **"This"** which refers to the `x:Name` of the content page. The `ViewModel` is just a strongly typed property of `ContentPage` which refers to the unboxed `BindingContext`.

Side note: The question refers to the .NET MAUI, however, I had to migrate back to the Xamarin Forms because at the time .NET MAUI has a lot of bugs that block development and app release. The problem is the same for both frameworks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Everdell.ViewModels;assembly=Everdell"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
    x:Class="Everdell.Views.SelectExpansionsView"
    x:DataType="vm:SelectExpansionsViewModel"
    x:Name="This">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <CheckBox>
            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                    EventName="CheckedChanged"
                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=ViewModel.SelectExpansionCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </CheckBox.Behaviors>
        </CheckBox>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure out this error for a week, I was trying access the viewmodel by AncestorType instead of x:Reference.

Answer (score 1):

In my case of observing exactly the same symptoms, I had to tweak the solution provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74474664/7733418) and  needed to change Path=ViewModel.xxxx to Path=BindingContext.xxxx for it to work. I don't know why the tweak was required, it could be version or framework dependent.

Unfortunately the event triggers on all checks, including data load and scroll into view.  This is a problem with the event itself though.

Comment: Are you attempting to answer the question at the top of this page? Your post seems to thank for and to discuss the existing answer (or maybe a comment.... hard to tell). If you do not attempt to answer according to [answer] please delete this. If you do, then please [edit] to make that more obvious.

Comment: My response was to the update below, thanking for the update but stating I needed to tweak it to actually make it work.  I made this comment in-case someone else requires the same tweak.  I don't know why the tweak was required, it could be version or framework dependent.

I will leave the comment as it adds value to the thread.

Comment: Please [edit] to make the post more obviously according to [answer] as much as possible. Referring to an existing answer and pointing out what additional insight/improvement you apply is fine. Try to avoid the impression of discussing a different solution which is different because your environment/problem is different - even if you do not know what the difference is. Also please understand that there is no "below", neither an "above". The order of displayed posts is individually configurable and hence for you unpredicatable. Use a link to the answer, even if currently there is only one.

Comment: I'm not changing anything.  The solution as described (in the same framework) did not work for me, I found a change that works, and commented the fix so that others may find it useful.  If you have nothing to add on this topic please refrain from commenting further as it's wasting both your time and  mine.  It's a comment on a forum, not a peer-review on a pull request. This will be my last response.

Comment: "It's a comment on a forum" No, it is neither a comment nor in something which is understood as a forum. It is an answering post in the Q/A collection which StackOverflow aspires to be. As such it should match [answer] as much as possible, minimise "thanks" and avoid answer which do not answer the single allowed question on a given page. Please take the [tour] to verify this. If you think that you see threads here you should do so. Also if you think that you can answer to an answer. Or if you think that you can contribute with e.g. "I had a similar but different problem which I solve by ....".

Comment: "observing exactly the same symptoms" is my understanding of the context. Feel free to review and [edit] to put it right if I am wrong. Then however we possibly are back to answering a different question than asked here.

Comment: That is correct. Although the accepted answer is comprehensible, I don't know where the answer owner got this property "ViewModel" from. Maybe it is related to Xamarin.Forms (I didn't find such property though) although the question owner is asking about .NET MAUI. So, use "BindingContext" to refer to the page's view model.