# How to make checkbox trigger a command when checked?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, controls, maui

I have a checkbox and a [RelayCommand] in the viewmodel that I want to link it to so that the command runs when the checkbox is ticked/unticked (ideally knowing the state of the checkbox as well) but I cannot seem to do it.

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Color="DarkGreen"
          Scale="1.2">
    <CheckBox.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="CheckedChanged"
            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:AdvanceViewModel}}, Path=CheckAnswerCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding MarksFromPoint}" />
    </CheckBox.Behaviors>
</CheckBox>
```

This is what I have tried currently but it gives me a System Exception: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object".

How do I make it work in the way I want.

I am using .NET 7 and using MAUI for the app. I have the Maui Community Toolkit in use as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Umm just use https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls and you have a command on CheckChanged

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate your issue and there's a [Command is missing on Checkbox control #7394](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7394) on Github, you can follow up there.

Also, you can refer to [EventToCommandBehavior throws InvalidOperationException in MAUI for checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74474664/9644964) which may provide a workaround to fix it.